# How to automatically resize columns in a listview?

Tags: winforms, powershell, listview, autosize

I'm trying to store the result of the following statement in a listview:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -ComputerName $server |
    Select-Object Name, ProcessId, Path
```

Everything works fine, but the problem is (as you can see in the image) the size of each columns doesn't fit automatically with is content.

I didn't find a lot about listview in PowerShell on the Internet so I'm asking to you.

```
$ListViewProcesses = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListView
$ListViewProcesses.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10, 10)
$ListViewProcesses.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(782, 484)
$ListViewProcesses.View = [System.Windows.Forms.View]::Details
$ListViewProcesses.LabelEdit = $false
$listviewProcesses.HideSelection = $false
$listviewProcesses.FullRowSelect = $True
$listviewProcesses.MultiSelect=$false
$listviewProcesses.GridLines = $True
$objFormProcesses.Controls.Add($listviewProcesses)
```

[image]

I've tried `$ListViewProcesses.AutoResizeColumns()`, but which parameters should I put inside? The columns header?

Answer (score 2):

The argument for **[the `AutoResizeColumns` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview.autoresizecolumns?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Forms_ListView_AutoResizeColumns_System_Windows_Forms_ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle_)** is of the type `System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle`.

You can check out [this MSDN page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.columnheaderautoresizestyle?view=netframework-4.7.2) for the enumeration values and what they mean. I assume you're looking for 2.

```
$ListViewProcesses.AutoResizeColumns(0)  # no resizing
$ListViewProcesses.AutoResizeColumns(1)  # base width on header length
$ListViewProcesses.AutoResizeColumns(2)  # base width on content length
```

Comment: That's it ! i've putted at the bottom of the function that fill up the listview and it worked!
Thanks !